# present perfect "have met you NOW" or simple past "met you NOW"

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I have made up the sentences below.

(1a) I have been unhappy for a long time. I have not talked to anyone until I **have met** you **now**.

(1b) I have been unhappy for a long time. I have not talked to anyone until I **met** you **now**.

Most my non-native English speaking friends think the **present perfect should be used to modify "now"**. My other friends think the simple past "met" should be used.

What is your opinion? Thanks.